# localStorage for users and new users (learning purpose)

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

After some hours of research I still haven't found out how I should store new users in `localStorage`.

I have 2 pages: 1 for login and 1 for register as it follows:

```
<div class="login-page">
<div class="form">
<form class="register-form">
<input type="text" placeholder="name"/>
<input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
<input type="text" placeholder="email id"/>
<button>Create</button>
<p class="message">Already Registered? <a href="#">Login</a></p>
</form>


<form class="login-form">
<input type="text" placeholder="user name"/>
<input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
<button>login</button>
<p class="message">Not registered? <a href="#"> Register </a></p>
</div>
</div>
```

Now I am trying to store the new registered users (in order to use them for login) into `localStorage` like this:

```
userData = {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Smith',
    email: 'admin@gmail.com',
    password: '123456789'
},
adminData;



localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(userData));
adminData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData'));
```

But unfortunately, I can't find any ideas around it. I know it's not such a good idea to store sensitive data on client side, but it's only for learning purpose.

Thanks

Comment: You need to get the data from the input form and store it into your userData object. Then save the object to local storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done is correct but for checking the variable value try alert instead of console, because I think you are not properly able to see the data or even you go to Developer Tools, Application Tab.
And If you can share your full code, maybe I can help you with it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="login-page">
      <div class="form">
        <form class="register-form">
          <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="name"/>
          <input id="passcode" type="password" placeholder="password"/>
          <input id="email" type="text" placeholder="email id"/>
          <button onclick="addToLocal()">Create</button>
          <p class="message">Already Registered? <a href="#">Login</a></p>
        </form>

        <form class="login-form">
          <input type="text" placeholder="user name"/>
          <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
          <button>login</button>
          <p class="message">Not registered? <a href="#"> Register </a></p>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  <script>
    function addToLocal() {
      var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
      var passcode = document.getElementById('passcode').value;
      var emailAddress = document.getElementById('email').value;
      var userDetails = {
        "username": username,
        "passcode": passcode,
        "emailAddress": emailAddress,
      }
      localStorage.setItem("userDetails", JSON.stringify(userDetails));
    }
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: code-only answers are never answers IMO - always add an explanation to help OP understand the problem/solution